# PHP Memcached with WHM Centos 6.5, PHP 5.5.16 and Apache 2.4

Tags: php, memcached, centos6, whm

I'm seriously loosing my patience with this one.

I tried to install PHP Pecl Memcached on the server with the above spec using the following approach:

```
Software > Module Installers > PHP Pecl
```

search for `memcache`

Installed first the `memcache 3.0.8`, which went all fine, but then trying to install `memcached 2.2.7` I get error saying:

```
configure: error: no, sasl.h is not available. Run configure with --disable-memcached-sasl to disable this check
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/memcached/configure --with-libmemcached-dir=no' failed
The memcached.so object is not in /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212
Tidying /usr/local/lib/php.ini...
No changes
Tidying /usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/php/54/etc/php.ini...
No changes
```

Any idea what I need to do to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [this link](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/php-pecl-module-installation-fails-198432.html), seems to be some problem with the location of memcache.so object file

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve the problem - after following the instructions and trying again - the problem is still there.

Answer (score -1):

The Error Message is clear. You need the cyrus-sasl-devel package installed.

Comment: Sorry - which part of the error message indicates that?